# Better way to use sessionfactory in hibernate + struts

Tags: hibernate, struts2

This is my service class having some methods which is performing CRUD operations, so my question is like is it a good way to always open session Factory for single method and close it after the method gets executes or is there any other way where only one session factory is made available across whole Web Application

```
 public class ContactService{
    public Contact add(Contact contact) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(contact);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return contact;
    }
    public Contact delete(Long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Contact contact = (Contact) session.load(Contact.class, id);
        if(null != contact) {
            session.delete(contact);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return contact;
    }

    public List<Contact> list() {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {

            contacts = (List<Contact>)session.createQuery("from Contact").list();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Session factory is for creating a new session, don't mess it up with the session manager, the one is responsible for managing your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Name `SessionFactoryManager.java` inside package `com.xyzapp.hibernate` like below

```
package com.xyzapp.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class SessionFactoryManager {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){

if(sessionFactory==null)
    //it search that hibernate.cfg.xml file is available in class path
    sessionFactory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

and whenever u need the object of SessionFactory call ones like below

```
package com.xyzapp.dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;


import com.xyzapp.hibernate.SessionFactoryManager;      //import in ur class and create Session factory static object and use with whole method in a class same for all classes

public class ContactNoDAO {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory=SessionFactoryManager.getSessionFactory();

public static String addContactNo(ContactNo contactno){
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tr=null;
    String id=null;
    try{
        tr=session.beginTransaction();
        id=session.save(contactno).toString();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(tr!=null)tr.rollback();

    }
    return id;
}
}
```

try to call sessionFactory once in ur class;

Answer (score 0):

you need to have session factory available for getting session for your DB access operations, if you close your sessionFactory then the connection pool, cashes etc will get cleaned.

So keep your session factory open for your application lifetime and close when you shutdown your application.

Refer:
[http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#close()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#close%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion Struts2+Spring+Hibernate integration.

make sure it,have you add spring,hibernate,struts2 dependencies.

Step1: applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

   <bean id="myDao" class="controller.DataBaseSessionFactory" scope="request" /> 
 </beans>
```

Step 2:

package controller;

```
 import model.HibernateUtil;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

public class DataBaseSessionFactory implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

private Session dbsession;
private Transaction tx;

public Session getDbsession() {
    return dbsession;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    try {
        dbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        System.err.print("obtained current session");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.err.print(e.getMessage() + "new session db created");
    }
    this.tx = dbsession.beginTransaction();
}

@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    System.err.print("transaction commited");
    this.tx.commit();
}

public void rollback() throws Exception {
    System.err.print("transaction rollback");
    this.tx.rollback();
}
}
```

and finally you can use your sessionfactory in Actionclass.

Step 3:Action.class

```
private DataBaseSessionFactory myDao;

ex(){
  Contact c=(Contact) myDao.getDbsession().get(Contact.class, id);
  List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>)session.createQuery(Contact.class).list();
}
```